# Maximum Allowed Time for Short Circuit

Tags: circuit-design, short-circuit

Is there a maximum amount of time a circuit or system is allowed to have a short circuit present? I'm asking this because I'm thinking about how fuses and Over-current IC's perform. There is a set amount of time where the circuit will be outputting more current than it should with these type of devices, so I was just curious if there was some kind of rule of thumb to follow when designing a Over-current or Short Circuit protection circuit.

Comment: Depends on the system. But fuses and such devices won't really protect the system against repetitive events unless the limits are so conservative as to impede the capability of the system. Even on ICs with such protection, the IC will eventually fail after entering and exiting thermal shutdown enough times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If thermal heating effect of the short circuit on a device is considered, the short should be removed before the device temperature rises higher than allowed. The repetition of such events will increase the probability of failure of the device
2. If the short circuit (over current protection) is implemented as a safety mechanism, it depends on the system being protected. If the device is sensitive or the protection of the user is of utmost priority (safety) then there are fast acting fuses
3. Slow fuses or PTCs also work as current limiting but slower. Here, it is assumed that the risk of the device failing permanently will be less.
4. If I am using a small fuse for a motor driver circuit,I don't want the fuse to trip every time motor takes the surge current. But when the motor is stalled, it shouldn't be in that condition for longer. Here I can use slow resettable fuses..for example.
5. Rule of thumb is application dependant. A shock for a person even for 20 ms can make his heart beat miss its rhythm.
6. Little fuse document as reference: defining the application type
   [image]
7. The PTCs are limited by number of such limit events, they are rated for such number of cycles.